# On the descent of noetherianess along completion

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, local-rings

Let $A$ be a commutative local ring with maximal ideal $m$ and $\hat{A}$ be its $m$-adic completion. Are there any non-trivial conditions on $A$, under which $\hat{A}$ noetherian implies $A$ noetherian?

Comment: As a remark, the $m$-adic completion might [not](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/05JA) be $m$-adically complete.